# Analytic conjugacy of vanishing holonomy groups implies analytic conjugacy of foliations

Tags: differential-equations, blow-ups, foliations, holonomy

i am reading and trying to do some exercises and problems of the book Lectures on Analytic Differential Equations- Y. Ilyashenko, S. Yakovenko.
I can not solve the problem 11.6 that says

Consider nondicritical foliations having at most three hyperbolic singularities on the exceptional divisor after blow-up.
Prove that for such singularities analytic conjugacy of the vanishing holonomy groups implies the conjugacy of the foliations.
In such case the vanishing holonomy group is always integrable?

Since the singularities are hyperbolic (the eigenvalues of the linearization matix are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$) then by the Poincaré-Dulac theorem you can think that the foliation near every singularity is equivalent to its linear part.
I can't see if for such foliations the vanishing holonomy group is always integrable, because if it is, i think i can solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: You mean "solvable" instead of "integrable", right? If that's the case then it is not true. Also, would you please care to formulate your problem as a question?

Comment: I mean integrable. i want to see if those foliations are always integrable.

Comment: Well, yes, but integrable foliations correspond to solvable holonomy groups. Anyway, generically these groups are not solvable or, said differently, the foliations are not integrable (by this, I mean existence of a first integral in the Darboux class or, more generally, in the Liouville class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in general the holonomy group is not solvable. Yet, this is how I'd tackle the exercise. (By the way, as it is posed the exercise cannot be solved: you need to assume that each eigenratio of both foliations agree, since holonomy conjugacy only provides equality up to $\mathbb Z$ and said eigenratios are local analytic invariants. I give a counterexample below.)

Since the singularities are hyperbolic and the foliation is not dicritical, the saturation of a transverse disc $\Sigma$ by the foliation is a neighbourhood of the exceptional divisor, except for the (at most) three transverse separatrices. Therefore if the holonomy groups (computed on $\Sigma$) are conjugate then the conjugacy extends to a fibered conjugacy between foliations by the classical path-lifting technique of Mattei-Moussu. This extension can also be performed up to the missing separatrices (at this stage one needs the eigenratio of the singularities to agree for both foliations). By blowing down, one obtains a conjugacy between the foliations as expected.

---

Let me give a counterexample to the exercise in its given form. Let $\mathcal F_{a,b,c}$ be the foliation defined by the differential $1$-form $$\mathrm d(\log(x^ay^b(x+y)^c))$$ with $a, b, c\notin \mathbb R$. Clearly the foliation satisfies the hypothesis of the exercise, and its vanishing holonomy group is the linear group $<h\exp(2i\pi a),h\exp(2i\pi b),h\exp(2i\pi c)>$. Therefore shifting $(a,b,c)$ by any element of $\mathbb Z^3$ gives identical groups. Since the eigenratios of the blown-up foliation are given by $(a,b,c)$ this proves that $\mathcal F_{a,b,c}$ and $\mathcal F_{a+k_a,b+k_b,c+k_c}$ cannot be conjugate as soon as one $k_*$ is nonzero.

Comment: Sure not enough dimension, my bad. Aaaaa of course ok ok. But if the conjugacy is analytical , if $\ f_1 , f_2 , f_3 $ and $\ g_1 , g_2 , g_3 $ are the generators of those two groups then you can choose them in a way that $\ f_i  \circ h = h \circ g_i $ ($\ h $ is the analytical germ that conjugates the groups) and it tells that the linear coefficient are the same, so in the end the singularities will have the same characteristic ratio, isn't it?

Comment: By the way, why is there a restriction in the number of singularities after blow up?

Comment: The linear part of the holonomy is an exponential, so they will have same ratios only up to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: As for the restriction on the number of singularities, I don't know. I'd say my argument works for any number of points (although the fact that the foliation is reduced after a single blow-up is essential).

Comment: Someone gave me this hint, with this way of solving the problem, the restriction of why just at most three singularities is maybe the way you solve the problem. I will put it in two parts becase it is too long.

If you have a foliation with at most three singularities on the exceptional divisor, then you can always assign these singularities at any three fixed points on the projective line. Moreover, you can map analytically the infinite divisor with the three transversal analytic separatrices of one foliation onto that of another.

Comment: Analytic conjugacy of the vanishing holonomy can then be extended to a conjugacy between foliations, defined in the complement to the above curves, and extended on the separatrices by the removable singularity theorem. After blowing down the picture, we can again use the removable singularity theorem to show that the analytic conjugacy defined on the complement to the origin, extends analytically at the origin.

Comment: Yes, right, otherwise the relative locations of the singularities are also invariant. Sorry I missed that in my answer. (Removable singularity theorem is indeed the way to go to extend the conjugacy to the separatrices, though I didn't mention it explicitly.)

Comment: That's the same, by compactness of the exceptional divisor. Look, Epet, I think we should stop adding on comments like this, I'm even going to remove some of mine, and I encourage you to do the same. This is going nowhere, this site is not for step-by-step solving problems.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  By the way i think you do not need that the characteristic ratios coincide between both foliations. Since this are foliations the analytic conjugacy is up to a non vanishing analytic function and then the ratios could be different. But if this were a vector fields problem the ratios must be the same. I think that is why that hypothesis is not necessary.

Comment: The *eigenvalues* are invariants for *vector fields*, but the *eigenratio* is invariant for *foliations*.